# Flutter (iOS) - Module 'cloud_firestore' not found in GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm a newborn in flutter environment.

I was trying to setup a Cloud Firestore connection to my app. I did most of the coding process on VSCode, but after implementing firestore, I tried building in Xcode since I got some error on VSCode.

Upon building my app in Xcode 12.5.1 (which I opened using Rosetta), I got this error
[Error when building app - Module 'cloud_firestore' not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBC7Y.png)

I've make sure to add the dependencies either in Podfile or in my Pubspec.yaml file.

Here is [My podfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70qgr.png) and here is my pubspec.yaml dependencies [pubspec.yaml dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpIyq.png)

I've tried several things such as:

1. Deintegrate pod and installing pod again(including deleting the podfile.lock and pods directory and reinstalling the pod again)
2. I've tried `flutter clean` -> `flutter pub get` -> `flutter build ios`, but still resulting in the same error.
3. I have imported my GoogleService-Info.plist to my Runner via Xcode and double checking the name.

What intrigue me is, I also add Firebase_auth package and it works just fine. See the error only showing at the  [import Cloud Firestore line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0Mzq.png)

Does anyone know how to resolve this error? Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you so much

Comment: same for me....

Comment: After days of scrolling through github and documentation, finally I found a way to work it out @SaurabhKumar

Comment: i just changed the ios version everywhere to 12 and it worked out.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Finally after days of trying and error, I found a way to work it out..

So, I noticed several things that might cause an error when building for iOS.

1. **Never** run the command `pod install` manually.
2. **Do not** add the line `pod install Firebase` to your podfile. Instead, just override all of the firebase dependencies using `$FirebaseSDKVersion = '8.0.0'`
3. Don't forget to specify your iOS Deployment target on your podfile and match it with the deployment target on your Runner.xcworkspace file (Both in the runner and in the target)

So, if you already have a project, here are the steps I recommend, as this works perfectly for me:

1. Delete the Pods directory, the /ios/podfile.lock, and the ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec
2. Run `pod deintegrate`
3. Delete all of the contents inside your DerivedData folder.. you can run `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*`
4. Run `flutter clean`
5. Run `flutter pub get`
6. Run `flutter build ios`. Note thas this will also run the `pod install` command.
7. Close your editor, and open your Runner.xcworkspace on XCode and run your XCode. Clean your build folder. If there's an option to update your project settings, accept it.

You might get several warnings about deprecated functions, but in my case, my app run just fine..

I don't know about the details on why it happened, but from what I noticed, Cocoapods have a different version of some of the firebase packages for ios.. I hope someone can explain it..

--

Things to note :

- If build your app on XCode, and then use `flutter run` either on terminal or VSCode, you would get some warnings like *Class AMSupportURLConnectionDelegate is implemented in both*. So, from my personal experience, I always run my app from XCode.
- If you use Google Sign In, follow the steps [here](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in) you don't need to add anything in your podfile.

For reference, here is my podfile content.

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
 # platform :ios, '12.0'

ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

$FirebaseSDKVersion = '8.0.0'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
     config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0'
     config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
    end
  end
end
```

I hope it works for you! Goodluck!

Comment: Since I run a multi-scheme project, I didn't do `Step 6` as per the recommendation. Instead, I manually ran `pod install` then went to `Step 7` to run my apps. Totally worked for all but 1 scheme, which seems to have been incorrectly configured? It still gets the same error and I noticed it is missing some settings in the `.plist` file. But thanks @reneconrad for your help.

Comment: Hey, @RealSollyM I got the same error regarding the .plist file when I try to implement Google Sign In.. 
.
So I followed the "Set Up Authentication" part on this website.. https://blog.codemagic.io/firebase-authentication-google-sign-in-using-flutter/
.
Hopefully it works for you :)

Comment: Adding this line in pod file fixed the issue for me

target.build_configurations.each do |config|
     config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0'
     config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
    end

Comment: I'm not sure why, but actually worked!

Answer (score 0):

Can you see that the `cloud_firestore` module has been successfully imported under your iOS project?

Comment: Hello, M_JSL! Thank you for taking the time to reply. 

The error message was as follow :
`/Path_To_My_App_ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:10:9: fatal error: module 'cloud_firestore' not found @import cloud_firestore;`

So I assume that cloud firestore has not been imported to my project.

Answer (score 0):

Non of the previous solutions worked for me. After two days of searching I downgraded cocoapods to an older version that I knew had worked in the past:

```
-COCOAPODS: 1.11.2
+COCOAPODS: 1.10.1
```

Uninstalled with `gem uninstall cocoapods` and installed the old version.
After that I applied @reneconrad's answer.