# module 'cloud_firestore' not found @import cloud_firestore

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
Hello, I've been stuck with this problem for a while: module 'cloud_firestore' not found @import cloud_firestore.
When I build my App Flutter on Xcode I get this error message and I can't fix it. I followed several tutorials here and elsewhere but nothing corrects my error, if someone knows how to fix it it would be a great help Thank you
```

![Icône de validation par la communauté](data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUCAQAAAAngNWGAAAA/0lEQVR4AYXNMSiEcRyA4cfmGHQbCZIipkuxnJgMStlMNmeyD2dwmc8+sZgxYJd9ErIZFHUyYYD7fkr6l4/rnvmtl7+KitrqV/fq2Y5eLY3Z9S48eRLe7BmVZ9qhTLhQ0algzZWQOVKSsCF8OjAnwbxDTWFDUhPK/jMr1H6HE/IqRky2DyvCefuwItwZzodVoYRiLqMkVCXrwpJ9twZ+sgfDYEFYl8wIWxZ9uFf7zkallxlJh4YrLGsKjZRx7VGHhLqwgFUN45DGdb8MeXGpgB4ABZdeDcpZEY51A+hyLKz4S1W4MQWm3AibWtgWmk6dyISa1pSdyWTOlLXVp0+eL9D/ZPfBTNanAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC)

```
I followed the process of several people who had the same problem, I put the links here, but it did not work for me : 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73917912/module-cloud-firestore-not-found-xcode-flutter

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68434062/flutter-ios-module-cloud-firestore-not-found-in-generatedpluginregistrant
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.